# how to replace a string at a specific position in a csv file using bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, cut

I have several .csv files and each csv file has lines which look like this.

```
AA,1,CC,1,EE
AA,FF,6,7,8,9
BB,6,7,8,99,AA
```

I am reading through each line of each csv file and then trying to replace the 4th position of each line beginning with AA with "ZZ"

Expected output

```
AA,1,CC,ZZ,EE
EE,FF,6,ZZ,8,9
BB,6,7,8,99,AA
```

However the variable "y" does contain the 4th variable "1" and "7" respectively, but when I use sed command it replaces the first occurrence of "1" with "ZZ".

How do I modify my code to replace only the 4th position of each line irrespective of what value it holds?

My code looks like this

$file = "name of file which contains list of all csv files"

```
for i in `cat file`
while IFS = read -r line;
do
if [[ $line == AA* ]] ; then
        y=$(echo "$line" | cut -d',' -f 4)
        sed -i "s/${y}/ZZ/" $i
fi
done < $i
```

Comment: Why did `AA` at the start of line 2 become `EE`?

Comment: Running `sed` on a line at a time is definitely a horrible antipattern. You want to process the entire file with a single process, and especialny, avoid rewriting the file multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`, you can also direct that only the 4th field of a comma separated values file be changed to `"ZZ"` for lines beginning `"AA"` with:

```
sed -i '/^AA/s/[^,][^,]*/ZZ/4' file
```

**Explanation**

- `sed -i` call `sed` to edit file in place;
- general form `/find/s/match/replace/occurrence`; where

  - `find` is `/^AA/` line beginning with `"AA"`;
  - `match` `[^,][^,]*` a character not a comma followed by any number of non-commas;
  - `replace` `/ZZ/4` the 4th occurrence of `match` with `"ZZ"`.

Note, both `awk` and `sed` provide good solutions in this case so see the answers by [@perreal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390913/perreal) and [@RavinderSingh13](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5866580/ravindersingh13)

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat file
AA,1,CC,1,EE
AA,FF,6,7,8,9
BB,6,7,8,99,AA
```

**Example Use/Output**

(**note:** `-i` not used below so the changes are simply output to `stdout`)

```
$ sed '/^AA/s/[^,][^,]*/ZZ/4' file
AA,1,CC,ZZ,EE
AA,FF,6,ZZ,8,9
BB,6,7,8,99,AA
```

Comment: It's a rather rare bird. I literally *stumbled* across it a couple of years back and just added it to my toolbox. It's application is tailored for `.csv` files, so it doesn't get a great deal of press. (`awk` taking the lions share there)

Comment: Hi. Instead of replacing content at the 4th location in a csv, I want to add it at the 4th position and move the older 4th position by one position to the right. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Yes, you can do it with a simple *backreference*, e.g. `. sed '/^AA/s/\([^,][^,]*\)/ZZ,\1/4' file` results in the first line of `AA,1,CC,ZZ,1,EE`, etc. Note: you are capturing the text between `\(....\)` and the reinserting that text with `\1` (first backrefernce) after you insert `ZZ,`.

Comment: great.this works. but do you have an elaborate explanation or a link for the same? I couldnt find much online.

Comment: It is the same explanation as in the answer, plus `\(...\)` which captures the text inside creating a back-reference to that text that lets you re-insert that text in the *"replace"* part of the substitution using `\1` (if you had a second `\(...\)` then you would use `\2` and so on...) See [5.7 Back-references and Subexpressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions.html) So you are just saving the 4th field in `\([^,][^,]*\)` and then replacing it with `ZZ,\1` -- which inserts `ZZ,` as the 4th filed and moves the original to the right.

Answer (score 2):

To robustly do this is just:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $1=="AA"{$4="ZZ"} 1' csv
AA,1,CC,ZZ,EE
AA,FF,6,ZZ,8,9
BB,6,7,8,99,AA
```

Note that the above is doing a literal string comparison and a literal string replacement so unlike the other solutions posted so far it won't fail if the target string (`AA` in this example) contains regexp metachars like `.` or `*`, nor if it can be part of another string like `AAX`, nor if the replacement string (`ZZ` in this example) contains backreferences like `&` or `\1`.

If you want to map multiple strings in one pass:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","; m["AA"]="ZZ"; m["BB"]="FOO"} $1 in m{$4=m[$1]} 1' csv
AA,1,CC,ZZ,EE
AA,FF,6,ZZ,8,9
BB,6,7,FOO,99,AA
```

and just like GNU sed has `-i` for "inplace" editing, GNU awk has `-i inplace`, so you can discard the shell loop and just do:

```
awk -i inplace '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
(NR==FNR) { ARGV[ARGC++]=$0 }
(NR!=FNR) && ($1=="AA") { $4="ZZ" }
{ print }
' file
```

and it'll operate on all of the files named in `file` in one call to awk. "file" in that last case is your file containing a list of other CSV file names.

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT1:*** Since OP has changed requirement a bit do adding following now.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} /^AA/||/^BB/{$4="ZZ"} /^CC/||/^DD/{$5="NEW_VALUE"} 1'  Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file
```

---

Could you please try following.

```
awk -F, '/^AA/{$4="ZZ"} 1' OFS=,  Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file
```

OR

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} /^AA/{$4="ZZ"} 1'  Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation to above code too now.

```
awk '
BEGIN{              ##Starting BEGIN section of awk which will be executed before reading Input_file.
  FS=OFS=","        ##Setting field separator and output field separator as comma here for all lines of Input_file.
}                   ##Closing block for BEGIN section of this program.
/^AA/{              ##Checking condition if a line starts from string AA then do following.
  $4="ZZ"           ##Setting 4th field as ZZ string as per OP.
}                   ##Closing this condition block here.
1                   ##By mentioning 1 we are asking awk to print edited or non-edited line of Input_file.
'  Input_file       ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: this should replace both the lines after do in the above code?

Comment: I just updated my question :) If the line begins with AA only i want to replace the 4th field

Comment: I will be reading through each line in the file in order to check whether it begins with AA or not. Could you please help me with the code? Thanks

Comment: Sure, once you add the explanation I will try it and definitely give an upvote.:)

Comment: this is printing the edited line but it is not actually making the edit to the file. WHat can be done for that?

Comment: @ShivaniSarin, on SO there is a way to tell thanks :) And let us delete all comments under this answer too to keep answer clean.

Comment: Hi. Instead of replacing content at the 4th location in a csv, I want to add it at the 4th position and move the older 4th position by one position to the right. Can you help me with this?

Comment: @ShivaniSarin, not clear, this is old thread you could better open a new thread with proper examples and mention your requirements in single post itself.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/\(^AA,[^,]*,[^,]*,\)[^,]*/\1ZZ/' input_file
```